# Unir consultas SQL agrupadas con distintas condiciones

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Tengo que hacer una consulta SQL donde tengo diferentes condiciones (where) y no puedo hacer que me salga todo en la misma consulta. 
Simplemente quiero que el resultado de la seguna consulta se pueda poner en una columna al final de la primera consulta.

**Consulta 1:**

```
SELECT till.code as maquina,
till.description as codigolocal,
count(ta.article_id) as nºarticulos,
groups.description as descripcionsubfamilia,
sum(t.total_amount) as ImporteBruto,
sum(t.total_amount) /1.1 as ImporteNeto,
(sum(t.total_amount)) - (sum(t.total_amount) /1.1) as importeImpuestos
    FROM [rtv_turnover_transaction] as t,
    rtv_trans_articles as ta,
    articles as art,
    groups,
    Clients as s,
    [rtv_transactions] as tr,
    tills as till,
    Ubicacion as u 
where t.transaction_id=ta.transaction_id and 
art.id=ta.article_id 
and s.id=t.cliente_id 
and tr.id=t.transaction_id
and groups.id=art.group_a_id 
and t.ubicacio_id=u.id 
and till.ID=t.till_id
and t.trans_date > getdate () -1 and s.id=3  group by till.code,till.description,groups.description
```

**Consulta 2:**

```
    Select sum(t.total_amount) as tarjeta

    FROM [rtv_turnover_transaction] as t,
    rtv_trans_articles as ta,
    articles as art,
    groups,
    Clients as s,
    [rtv_transactions] as tr,
    tills as till,
    Ubicacion as u 
where t.transaction_id=ta.transaction_id and 
art.id=ta.article_id 
and s.id=t.cliente_id 
and tr.id=t.transaction_id
and groups.id=art.group_a_id 
and t.ubicacio_id=u.id 
and till.ID=t.till_id
and t.trans_date > getdate () -1 and s.id=3 and tr.card_num is not null group by till.code,till.description,groups.description
```

Comment: Has probado a hacer una Join (https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)? Si en la segunda consulta haces select también de la clave primaria puedes hacer una Join de ambas consultas.. pero ten en cuanta que las columnas "efectivo" de ambios selects no podrán llamarse igual.

Comment: Te rogaría que en vez de pegar imágenes, pegases el texto de las consultas. Así podríamos copiar y pegar y sería más fácil ayudarte. Gracias

Comment: ¿Conseguiste solucionarlo? Por favor, marca como respuesta válida la que te haya solucionado el problema. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que debes hacer es unir las dos consultas por los campos en común, como si fuesen una única consulta con una columna más al final (que es lo que tú buscas). Si te fijas, las columnas que empiezan por "a." son las de la primera consulta y la última columna, la que empieza por "b." es la que quieres añadir al final:

```
select a.maquina, a.codigolocal, a.[nºarticulos], a.descripcionsubfamilia, a.ImporteBruto, a.ImporteNeto, a.importeImpuestos, a.efectivo, b.efectivo
    from (
        SELECT till.code as maquina,
        till.description as codigolocal,
        count(ta.article_id) as nºarticulos,
        groups.description as descripcionsubfamilia,
        sum(t.total_amount) as ImporteBruto,
        sum(t.total_amount) /1.1 as ImporteNeto,
        (sum(t.total_amount)) - (sum(t.total_amount) /1.1) as importeImpuestos
            FROM [rtv_turnover_transaction] as t,
            rtv_trans_articles as ta,
            articles as art,
            groups,
            Clients as s,
            [rtv_transactions] as tr,
            tills as till,
            Ubicacion as u 
        where t.transaction_id=ta.transaction_id and 
        art.id=ta.article_id 
        and s.id=t.cliente_id 
        and tr.id=t.transaction_id
        and groups.id=art.group_a_id 
        and t.ubicacio_id=u.id 
        and till.ID=t.till_id
        and t.trans_date > getdate () -1 and s.id=3  group by till.code,till.description,groups.description
    ) as a
    inner join 
    (
        select till.code as maquina, 
        till.description as codigolocal,
        groups.description as descripcionsubfamilia,
        sum(t.total_amount) as efectivo
            FROM [rtv_turnover_transaction] as t,
            rtv_trans_articles as ta,
            articles as art,
            groups,
            Clients as s,
            [rtv_transactions] as tr,
            tills as till,
            Ubicacion as u 
        where t.transaction_id=ta.transaction_id and 
        art.id=ta.article_id 
        and s.id=t.cliente_id 
        and tr.id=t.transaction_id
        and groups.id=art.group_a_id 
        and t.ubicacio_id=u.id 
        and till.ID=t.till_id
        and t.trans_date > getdate () -1 and s.id=3 and tr.card_num is not null group by till.code,till.description,groups.description
    ) as b
    on a.maquina = b.maquina and a.codigolocal = b.codigolocal and a.descripcionsubfamilia = b.descripcionsubfamilia
```

Comment: Buenas Carlos. Me he explicado mal. No quiero juntar las columnas, simplemente quiero que el resultado de la segunda consulta se ponga en una última columna junto al resultado de la primera.

Comment: Eso es lo que hecho ¿no? :)

Comment: Tu consulta me da 5 filas y debería tener 3, como las dos consultas separadas.

Comment: Ahora que has cambiado el código de imágenes a texto, te he copiado las consultas completas. ¿Puedes comprobar que solo devuelva 3 filas ahora, por favor? Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Crea un row_number en c/u y unelas por ese campo.

```
select t1.* from 
(
select *, row_number() over (order by maquina) a from
(
SELECT till.code as maquina,
till.description as codigolocal,
count(ta.article_id) as nºarticulos,
groups.description as descripcionsubfamilia,
sum(t.total_amount) as ImporteBruto,
sum(t.total_amount) /1.1 as ImporteNeto,
(sum(t.total_amount)) - (sum(t.total_amount) /1.1) as importeImpuestos
    FROM [rtv_turnover_transaction] as t,
    rtv_trans_articles as ta,
    articles as art,
    groups,
    Clients as s,
    [rtv_transactions] as tr,
    tills as till,
    Ubicacion as u 
where t.transaction_id=ta.transaction_id and 
art.id=ta.article_id 
and s.id=t.cliente_id 
and tr.id=t.transaction_id
and groups.id=art.group_a_id 
and t.ubicacio_id=u.id 
and till.ID=t.till_id
and t.trans_date > getdate () -1 and s.id=3  group by till.code,till.description,groups.description   ) t1
) t1 join

(
select *, row_number() over (order by tarjeta) b from

(
  Select sum(t.total_amount) as tarjeta

FROM [rtv_turnover_transaction] as t,
rtv_trans_articles as ta,
articles as art,
groups,
Clients as s,
[rtv_transactions] as tr,
tills as till,
Ubicacion as u 
where t.transaction_id=ta.transaction_id and 
art.id=ta.article_id 
and s.id=t.cliente_id 
and tr.id=t.transaction_id
and groups.id=art.group_a_id 
and t.ubicacio_id=u.id 
and till.ID=t.till_id
and t.trans_date > getdate () -1 and s.id=3 and tr.card_num is not null group by till.code,till.description,groups.description) t1

) t2 on t1.a = t2.b
```

Comment: No me acaba de salir tu solución. He pegado los códigos de la consulta por si puedes usar ese formato en mi consulta.

Comment: update agregado.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar creando una tabla temporal con WITH por ejemplo:

```
WITH TablaTemporal [(campos devueltos)]
AS (
--Aqui toda tu subconsulta    
)
--Aqui la otra consulta
SELECT * FROM TablaTemporal t, OtrasTablas...
```

Tu resultado de la primera subconsulta se ejecutara y se guardara en una tabla temporal con el Alias que tu le llames y podras acceder a ella en otra consulta mas. No he usado esta sentencia en SQL-Server pero en Oracle sirve bastante.

Fuente: https://www.campusmvp.es/recursos/post/SQL-Server-Expresiones-de-tabla-comunes.aspx